An interesting difference between Plain-TeX and LaTeX with `hfilneg` in TeXBook-Glue-Question12.17
The Question12.17 in the TeXBook is:

Describe the result of \line{\hfil A puzzle.\hfilneg}


You get ‘A’ at the extreme left and ‘puzzle.’ at the extreme right, because the
space between words has the only stretchability that is finite; the infinite stretchability
cancels out. (In this case, TEX’s rule about infinite glue differs from what you would
get in the limit if the value of 1 fil were finite but getting larger and larger. The true
limiting behavior would stretch the text ‘A puzzle.’ in the same way, but it would also
move that text infinitely far away beyond the right edge of the page.)

When I use the tex in commandline to executed the \line{\hfil A puzzle.\hfilneg} with Plain-TeX, I get the texput.dvi file shown as below:

However, I found that there is no command \line with LaTeX2e, and when I use the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\hfil A puzzle. \hfilneg
\end{document}


I have two questions:

What cause the difference between two engines?
A glue with positive shrink(like \hskip 0pt minus 1fil) and the glue with negative stretch(like \hskip 0pt plus -1fil) , what is the difference?  And I didn't make clear sense to the answer, can somebody paraphase it more detailedly?

I wonder if my thoughts on the answer is correct here:
The First Glue with plus 1fil push the ALL item A puzzle to right with 1fil's force, and the Last Gule with plus -1fil pull all the sentence back, which offset with same level of force. Finally, as if only the glue of the <space> that worked, and push A and puzzle. to each side.

The plain TeX puzzle relies on \line being defined as
\hbox to \hsize

LaTeX has \line, but it's for picture mode.
If you do
\noindent X\dotfill X

\hfil A puzzle\hfilneg
\bye

in plain TeX you get

because the \hfilneg glue is removed by (the implicit) \par and \parfillskip glue is added, so the effect is centering. Exactly the same as you get in LaTeX with the code you show.
The LaTeX version of the puzzle would be
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth][s]{\hfil A puzzle\hfilneg}

\end{document}


You get the same warning
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 7
 \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 A puzzle


What about \line{\hfil A puzzle\hfilneg}? If I do
\setbox0=\hbox{A puzzle.}\showbox0

I get
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x40.83339
.\tenrm A
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66498 minus 1.11221
.\tenrm p
.\tenrm u
.\tenrm z
.\tenrm z
.\tenrm l
.\tenrm e
.\tenrm .

So the natural width of the box is 40.83339pt. With
\line{\hfil A puzzle.\hfilneg}

the natural width is still 40.83339pt, but TeX is ordered to stretch (because the natural width is less than the desired width) the box to be \hsize wide. At this point the available glue is examined. I'll only show the stretch components:
0pt plus 1fil
3.33333pt plus 1.66498pt
0pt plus -1fil

because \hfil and \hfilneg are as shown above. Then TeX sums all available stretch components as if they were four dimensional vectors: finite stretchability and then first, second, third order infinite glue. We get
(1.66498,1-1,0,0)

so in the end the vector is
(1.66498,0,0,0)

No infinite glue is available. However, there is finite stretchability, which can expand to whatever it's needed, with influence on the badness. Indeed, you get an underfull box message. With
\setbox0=\hbox{A puzzle.}\showbox0
\setbox0=\line{\hfil A puzzle.\hfilneg}\showbox0

you get
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x469.75499, glue set 257.61397
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\tenrm A
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66498 minus 1.11221
.\tenrm p
.\tenrm u
.\tenrm z
.\tenrm z
.\tenrm l
.\tenrm e
.\tenrm .
.\glue 0.0 plus -1.0fil

> \box0=
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x469.75499, glue set 257.61397
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\tenrm A
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66498 minus 1.11221
.\tenrm p
.\tenrm u
.\tenrm z
.\tenrm z
.\tenrm l
.\tenrm e
.\tenrm .
.\glue 0.0 plus -1.0fil

You see the same glue set factor.

Yes, actually the \makebox show the same behavior as Plain-TeX, however there still remains vague on the difference between positive shrink(like \hskip 0pt minus 1fil) and the glue with negative stretch(like \hskip 0pt plus -1fil). Thanks uuuuuu so much.

@Explorer I added a detailed discussion of the puzzle.

yes, I learn that, and I think that I have known the diffenece between \hskip 0pt minus 1fil and \hskip 0pt plus -1fil. With the case in Question12.17, both two stretch glue offset, white with \hfil A puzzle.\hskip 0pt minus 1fil, the A puzzle. will be pushed right with the Left stretch and Right shrink glue. thanks very much!

@Explorer The stretch and shrink components are independent of each other; TeX uses the former when stretching is needed and the shrink component is not looked at. I think that using the keywords stretch and shrink would have been less confusing.

yes, plus and minus is a bit like some algebraic operation, and a little confusing with minus -1fil equals to plus 1fil, which the properties is quite opposite and independent, thanks!
